# Why EF Core database first foreign key is not working as expected here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I am using EF Core Database First Approach, where I have a one to many relationship in two tables.
visit and expense_details table.
Here one visit may have zero or multiple entry in expense_details table
I defined foreign key relationship between those, but, when I run the project the resulted JSON returns NULL for Visit property in Expense_details object and same happens in case of expense property in Visit Object.

My Database Objects are:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[visit](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tour_id] [int] NULL,
    [description] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [subject_to] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [start_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [start_time] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [end_time] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [start_location] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [destination_location] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [start_mileage] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [end_mileage] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_visit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[expense_details](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [visit_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [expense_category_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [expense_amount] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [remarks] [varchar](200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_expense_details] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[expense_details]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_expense_details_visit] FOREIGN KEY([visit_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[visit] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[expense_details] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_expense_details_visit]
GO
```

These are the generated Model class after scaffolding db

```
     public partial class Visit
        {
            public Visit()
            {
                ExpenseDetails = new HashSet<ExpenseDetail>();
            }
    
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public int? TourId { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string SubjectTo { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public string StartTime { get; set; }
            public string EndTime { get; set; }
            public string StartLocation { get; set; }
            public string DestinationLocation { get; set; }
            public decimal StartMileage { get; set; }
            public decimal EndMileage { get; set; }
    
            public virtual ICollection<ExpenseDetail> ExpenseDetails { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public partial class ExpenseDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int VisitId { get; set; }
        public int ExpenseCategoryId { get; set; }
        public decimal ExpenseAmount { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        public virtual Visit Visit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ModelBuilder objects are:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseDetail>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("expense_details");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

            entity.Property(e => e.ExpenseAmount)
                .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)")
                .HasColumnName("expense_amount");

            entity.Property(e => e.ExpenseCategoryId).HasColumnName("expense_category_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Remarks)
                .HasMaxLength(200)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("remarks");

            entity.Property(e => e.VisitId).HasColumnName("visit_id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Visit)
                .WithMany(p => p.ExpenseDetails)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.VisitId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_expense_details_visit");
        });






[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Visit> Get()
        {
            var visit = tourActivityExpenseContext.Visits
                            .Include(e => e.ExpenseDetails)
                            .ToList();
            return visit;
        }
```

I am not sure if I need to manually impose something in code?

Comment: PLEASE show us your code...

Comment: It is possible that everything is fine - you just have lazy loading (or something like that) - you may just need to "include" the details explicity when you load visit (I would probably think in general you shouldn't load details without a visit - so always load a visit with details to get details. Welcome to EF - this is supposedly all great!

Comment: @topsail I added include option, it throws a json exception=> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected

Comment: I do not see any code which executes query. If you serialize model to JSON it is wrong, it should be projection to DTO, but workaround is simple - add `AsNoTracking()` to the end of the query.

Comment: @ 
Svyatoslav Danyliv, I updated question

Comment: Just throwing out some ideas from this post [cycle detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859589/system-text-json-jsonexception-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-n) which is to 1) add a JsonIgnore attribute to the virtual visit property in expense details, or 2) to use Newtonsoft Json instead of System.Text.Json for serialization, or to 3) just remove the backreference to visit in the expense details - you shouldn't need it (necessarily) - I think I have previously done both 2) and 3) , now that I think of it, but 1) also sounds like it would work as well.